# Saving Twitter authentication token and consumer key in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-oauth

I am trying to fetch the Twitter feeds by adding the twitter ids into my Rails application.

I have generated the secret token and consumer keys by registering my app with twitter and I want to save them in code i.e. in Rails application settings as I don't want to go with creating database migrations for my original settings. After a research I found this piece code useful:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'oauth'
```

`CONSUMER_KEY = "(your consumer key)"`
    `CONSUMER_SECRET = "(your consumer secret)"`

```
consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,:http_method=>:get, :site =>  "http://api.twitter.com")
```

`request_token = consumer.get_request_token` 
   `request_token.authorize_url`

```
require 'twitter'

oauth_verifier = "(a number shown on the user authorization screen)"

access_token = request_token.get_access_token(:oauth_verifier => oauth_verifier )
token = access_token.token
secret = access_token.secret

Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = CONSUMER_KEY
  config.consumer_secret = CONSUMER_SECRET
  config.oauth_token = token
  config.oauth_token_secret = secret 
end`
```

I found this above piece of code useful and successfully tested it with my twitter authentication consumer keys in irb console. Now, I want to use this in my rails application, but I don't know where to place this code so that I can easily start fetching the Twitter feeds.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use **omniauth** gem as its the best of authentication with many social networking sites and it also have good documentation.
One more thing its also compatible with devise and many more.

Checkout this links:
[Omniauth gem](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth)

[Omniauth+devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview)